# vw polo 6n2 oil level decreasing

Tags: engine, oil, vw, polo

i have a Volkswagen polo 1.4 engine i have two problem first in oil level, the oil level is decreasing every few days and there is no oil leak or no smoke going out from the exhaust, and second problem is white smoke comes out when i'm going up a mountain i don't know if the two problems related to each other or not can any one help me please ?

Comment: How about the coolant level? Does it decrease too? Does it look like brown pudding?

Comment: yes it is decreasing also but no brown pudding

Comment: Strange, but if the coolant is decreasing also, and you can't spot any leaks of coolant either, you probably have a faulty headgasket. That white smoke has to come from somewhere.

Comment: white smoke is just appearing when going up a mountain